# How can I use the Eckert IV projection with GeoServer WMS?

Tags: geoserver, wms, equal-area

I'm trying to request a map in the Eckert IV using a WMS hosted by GeoServer. When I set `srs=EPSG:54012` in my query string, I just get a sad XML response:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE ServiceExceptionReport SYSTEM "http://172.17.0.2:8080/geoserver/schemas/wms/1.1.1/WMS_exception_1_1_1.dtd"> 
<ServiceExceptionReport version="1.1.1" > 
  <ServiceException code="InvalidSRS">
      Error occurred decoding the espg code EPSG:54012
No code &quot;EPSG:54012&quot; from authority &quot;European Petroleum Survey Group&quot; found for object of type &quot;IdentifiedObject&quot;.
  </ServiceException>
</ServiceExceptionReport>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

Had I actually read the complete [blog post from GeoSolutions](http://www.geo-solutions.it/blog/developers-corner-adding-two-global-equal-area-projections-to-geotoolsgeoserver/), I wouldn't have had a problem.

It turns out that while GeoServer is capable of rendering a map in this projection, it doesn't ship with a SRS definition.

You can add this by creating the following file in your data directory: `DATA_DIR/user_projections/epsg.properties`. Then, populate the file with the WKT definition as follows (you can look it up at [spatialreference.org](http://www.spatialreference.org), but I had to modify that version a bit before GeoServer would accept it):

```
54012=PROJCS["World_Eckert_IV", \
  GEOGCS["GCS_WGS_1984", \
    DATUM["WGS_1984", \
      SPHEROID["WGS_1984",6378137,298.257223563]], \
    PRIMEM["Greenwich", 0.0 ], \
    UNIT["Degree", 0.017453292519943295]], \
  PROJECTION["Eckert_IV"], \
  PARAMETER["Central_Meridian", 0.0], \
  UNIT["Meter", 1.0], \
  AUTHORITY["EPSG","54012"]]
```

You'll need to reboot GeoServer to get it to see the file.

Comment: http://epsg.io/54012 - would possibly work without changes? It is more up todate/supported than spatialrerence.org

Comment: @IanTurton I think they're the same in this case. When I used the definition as-is, GeoServer gave me the rather indecisive pair of errors: `Parameter "False_Easting" was unexpected. Parameter "False_Easting" is missing.` I removed the `False_Easting` and `False_Northing` parameters from the definition, et voila.